# Is there a way to combine these two if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement, jframe

I was working on a personal assignment where the user types their birthday, and then it displays the user's astrological sign and a description of the sign. But since all astrological signs are multiple months, I have split the if statements into multiple if statements, one for each month, for example

```
if (birthMonth == 5 && (21<=birthDay && birthDay <=31)) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        String symbol = "Your sign is Gemini. You are cerebral, chatty, love learning and education, charming, and adventurous.   ";
        symbol += bday;
        JLabel label = new JLabel(symbol, new ImageIcon("gemini.jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    else if (birthMonth == 6 && (1<=birthDay && birthDay <=21)) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        String symbol = "Your sign is Gemini. You are cerebral, chatty, love learning and education, charming, and adventurous.   ";
        symbol += bday;
        JLabel label = new JLabel(symbol, new ImageIcon("gemini.jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to combine the if statements, while keeping the code working the way it currently is. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: WHy dont you use || ?
like this: (birthMonth == 5 && (21<=birthDay && birthDay <=31) || (birthMonth == 6 && (1<=birthDay && birthDay <=21)))

Comment: Just combine them with an or. Seems simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both logic and behavior are same so you don't have to use two condition to write your logic you can use below code as a single way.

```
if (birthMonth == 5 && (21<=birthDay && birthDay <=31) || birthMonth == 6 && (1<=birthDay && birthDay <=21)) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        String symbol = "Your sign is Gemini. You are cerebral, chatty, love learning and education, charming, and adventurous.   ";
        symbol += bday;
        JLabel label = new JLabel(symbol, new ImageIcon("gemini.jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Most of those parentheses are redundant. `(birthMonth == 5 && 21<=birthDay && birthDay <=31 || birthMonth == 6 && 1<=birthDay && birthDay <=21)` would work identically.

Comment: Yes, but i have included bracket to better understand the code implementation.

Comment: @GauravRai1512 Do you know how to add a new line to the string symbol? \n doesn't appear to work in JFrame.

Comment: let me know where you want to use new line do you have any code for reference?

Comment: @GauravRai1512 In this line `String symbol = "Your sign is Gemini. You are cerebral, chatty, love learning and education, charming, and adventurous.   ";`

Comment: @GauravRai1512 Done, and also, if I need to add a new string in order to get a new line, that will work too, as long as you tell me how to add the second string to the JLabel

Comment: please try below example for next lineSystem.out.println("I\nam\na\nboy");

System.out.println("I am a boy".replaceAll("\\s+","\n"));

System.out.println("I am a boy".replaceAll("\\s+",System.getProperty("line.separator")));

Comment: @GauravRai1512 Are you experienced in JFrame? I'm thinking about making a new question about the JFrame problem later.

Comment: @AlexPeters Alex i have little bit idea about JFrame. have you tried JLabel concept to break the line. Surround the string with <html></html> and break the lines with <br>. maybe you can use this concept in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the or operator || ? like this:

```
(birthMonth == 5 && (21<=birthDay && birthDay <=31) || (birthMonth == 6 & (1<=birthDay && birthDay <=21)))
```